# Chinese Remainder Theorem quiz question not right?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

[Why is answer 2 not right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgsDK.png)

To apply Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve a system of modular equations all the moduli have to be pairwise relatively prime. Given the following system of modular equations:

$x\equiv 3\pmod 3$

$x\equiv 5\pmod 9$

$x\equiv 4\pmod 5$

we should only select the following in order to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem:

$x\equiv 5\pmod 9$

$x\equiv 4\pmod 5$.

Why is this the case? I think $x\equiv 3\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv 4 \pmod5$ should also be right since you can't fully solve the system of modular equations either way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Tosolve *this* system, I'd rather consider only the mod 3 and mod 9 equation as only this pair implies the correct answer:  that no solution exists

Comment: The first two congruences contradict. The first means that $x$ is divisible by $3$ , the second that it is not.

Comment: That quiz question is *very poorly posed*. It is not clear if they are trying to get you to select two equations to which CRT applies (i.e. with coprime moduli), or whether they are attempting to get you to select the two equations which prove the system of three equations is unsolvable by the generalized solvability criterion.

Answer (score 1):

**@alramdkwan**, first, welcome to MSE.

Now, concerning your question, I think that it already implies that there is no solution exists because:

1. $x \equiv 3 \pmod{3}$ means $x$ is divisible by 3
2. $x \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$ means $x$ is **not** divisible by 3

The two conditions above yield the result of no $x$,

About your solution, I think it is true that in two cases you have two answers. But this is not incorrect. It rather leads you to the conclusion that this system has no solution.

Comment: Or you can say $x \equiv 5 \pmod 9 \implies x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.